# Content of "Ng-If ="0" <div>" shows on un-"collapse"

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The content of the `ng-if` still shows if I click the button. But I want it only to show in a specific situation. In another situation the button should unhide a different `<div>`

I thought the part after `ng-if` gets removed in the DOM, so I am wondering why it is even able to show up.

```html
<tr>
  <td>{{approval_item.requested_for}}</td>
  <td><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".{{approval_item.document_id_number}}"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
</tr>

<div ng-if="0">
  <tr class="hide-table-padding collapse {{approval_item.document_id_number}}">
    <td colspan="5">
      <tr class="collapse {{approval_item.document_id_number}}">
        <td><b>Item / Service</b></td>
        <td><b>Quantity</b></td>
        <td><b>One-time Price</b></td>
        <td><b>Monthly</b></td>
        <td><b>Yearly</b></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="collapse {{approval_item.document_id_number}}" ng-repeat="requested_item in approval_item.request_ritms">
        <td><a href="{{requested_item.link}}">{{requested_item.name}}</a></td>
        <td>{{requested_item.quantity}}</td>
        <td>{{requested_item.price_string}}</td>
        <td>{{requested_item.price_monthly_string}}</td>
        <td>{{requested_item.price_yearly_string}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="collapse {{approval_item.document_id_number}}">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><b>One-time Total</b></td>
        <td><b>Monthly Total</b></td>
        <td><b>Annually Total</b></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="collapse {{approval_item.document_id_number}}">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>{{approval_item.price_string}}</td>
        <td>{{approval_item.price_monthly_string}}</td>
        <td>{{approval_item.price_yearly_string}}</td>
      </tr>
    </td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to use [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/)? It's kind of a dead project and replaced by [Angular](https://angular.io/).

Comment: This is exactly what `ng-if` does (https://codepen.io/moshfeu/pen/JjrWGaa). Can you see errors in the console  maybe?

Comment: @jabaa I am working in ServiceNow with it, and they use AngularJS

Comment: @moshfeu Unfortunately there is no error in the log. It just shows whats in the div..

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `div` can't be a child of `table`.
If you want to hide the row, you should remove the `div` and move the `ng-if` into the `tr` itself.

**Do**

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller("Ctrl_List", ["$scope", function(s) {}])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="Ctrl_List">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          row 1
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-if="0">
        <td>
          row 2
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Don't**

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller("Ctrl_List", ["$scope", function(s) {}])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="Ctrl_List">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          row 1
        </td>
      </tr>
      <div ng-if="0">
        <tr>
          <td>
            row 2
          </td>
        </tr>
      </div>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```